# How do I run Urban Code Deploy FVT tests locally?

Tags: ucd

My project at work used Urban Code Deploy (UCD) for its continuous deployment process.  My code runs locally and passes all unit tests, but the build group says that my code is failing the FVT test being run by UCD.  Is there any way to run this FVT test locally, or at least attempt to run it, so I can hopefully figure out what is failing?

Mike

Answer (score 1):

UC Deploy isn't a testing tool. So the team that has set it up, has it running some other testing tool at the end of hte deployment (which is pretty normal).

So you'll need to ask them what testing tool they're using and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see how the build group is deploying your code, you should be able to see what testing they are doing, and then be able to replicate that in your own environment.  Often the code changes and changes in requirements will not be reflected in the FVT tests, and you need to deliver updated FVT test scripts in conjunction with your code changes.